# Bizarre exceptions being thrown in android activity

Tags: android, android-activity

So, I have an android app to finish making for a project, the same one as I asked questions about here before but this time I'm having trouble with a completely different aspect. Since the app is about Pokémon, in one activity I have some TextViews, EditTexts and a button set up to make an IV calculator. If you're curious and don't know what "IVs" are in Pokémon, google it of course. Anyway, getting back on track...this image here I put together highlights my problem

[image]

Above the boxed line you see there is a ClassCastException thrown  saying cannot cast from type TextView to EditText...I know what that means in a general sense but I cannot fathom why it is occurring here because as you can see in the relevant line of code (which i pasted into the image) the part of that line that involves casting is casting from View (return type of findViewById) to EditText. The arg R.id.EditText06 IS referring to an EditText in my activity so I don't see where the bad casting attempt is supposedly occurring. Just for a little clarification of the context of this, this is part of stuff coded into the OnClickListener of the button.

Apologies if this question seems perhaps incomplete as regards content shown about the problem but it is quite late for me (so much so that I'm going to bed upon posting this) and please do ask for me to post other stuff if you feel you need it to try to help me.

EDIT: here is my xml file for the activity in question. http://pastebin.com/g5B8d393

EDIT2: OK now this is getting worse :( My current setup is that I have a sort of dummy main activity with just a button to launch an activity. While testing I changed which one it was to launch as desired...until some time last night (and I really don't see what could've started this problem) it worked fine with my `IVCalculatorActvity` once I had it working fully and properly, and with the other activity. But now, it just crashes when I hit the button in the main activity...I'm just going to upload the project somewhere. (http://www.filehosting[DOT]org/file/details/429262/PokeUtility.zip)
Grrr...curse this reputation restriction on link posting >.>
I understand the reasoning but meh...

EDIT3: apologies for ssuch sudden editing but I only just saw you latest post now HalR. Testing app atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findViewById` doesn't return an object of class View, but of whatever class that object is indicated in your XML file.  Whatever you think you are describing your EditText06 as in your XML, it thinks its a `TextView` instead of and `EditText`.  Double check and make sure you aren't defining the `id="EditText06"` in more than one spot.

If you show your xml, It would likely be easier for someone to point out the specific problem in your xml file.

You need to use the format "@+id/..." once for each label, the first time it shows up (either as a reference or as an id".  Otherwise you generate multiple labels. I edited your file the way I think it needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".IVCalculatorActivity" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/calculate" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText01"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewD"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textViewD"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText05"
            android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText03"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText02"
            android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText04"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText03"
            android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewA"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewC"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/IVcalcHeader" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@id/textViewC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textViewD"
            android:layout_below="@id/textViewA"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:text="Stat" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@id/EditText05"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textViewC"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textViewC"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/textViewA"
            android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@id/textViewD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewB"
            android:layout_below="@id/EditText05"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Stat value" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText02"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textViewB"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textViewB"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/EditText01"
            android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@id/textViewB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView5"
            android:layout_below="@id/EditText01"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:text="Level" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView6"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="EV count" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/button3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/EditText03"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:text="Base Stat" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView6"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView6"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Nature" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/EditText04"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/button3"
            android:text="      " />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText06"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textViewE"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textViewE"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView7"
            android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ugh...wishing now I remembered to upload my stuff to online storage last night :/ And yea I understand that it doesn't quite return something of type View, I just meant like how the **return type** of the method is View since TextView, etc are subclasses of View and can be treated as a View object, hence the requirement to cast what's returned from `findViewById`

Comment: I'd be happy to look at your stuff, if its up some where.

Comment: Hmm...I copied in that XML and it works fine again now, the `IVCalculatorActivity` that is...if you got to the "pseudo-link" I edited into my question above you can get the full project. Currently the app crashes when the main activity button is set to launch `TypeActivity`.

Comment: Also, did you do a full clean of your project and rebuild?

Comment: Well, one problem now is, logcat seems to be showing absolutely nothing. :/ Hang on I'll see if restarting eclipse does any good. Actually yeah I for got about that clean function...trying that first

Comment: Ok after cleaning logcat seems to be ok but I got errors (not the same as before) see here : http://oi47.tinypic.com/dmskkk.jpg

Comment: (facepalm) never mind my last "problem"...in `TypeActivity` I was referencing `R.id.button1` when it should've been `R.id.button2` I think I should be ok for now, with these parts at least...thanks for helping.